# What are the correct xs:ID allowable id names?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, w3c, xml-validation

I am trying to define an ID for `id` attribute of one of the tags. The documentation and xsd schema mandates to confirm the id set with `xs:id`.

I tried `"ID_123"` that worked but when I tried `"123"`, it did not. I googled on the options and some examples a lot but couldn't find anything besides the text written [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re74.html).

Could some please provide some examples here and what characters are allowed? To my understanding, any alphanumeric characters should work but seems there should be a combination of alphabets (or the word `ID`?) and numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/) defines `xs:ID`:

> [**3.4.8 ID**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#ID)
>
> [Definition:]  `ID` represents the `ID` attribute type from[[XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#XML)].
> The ·value space· of ID is the set of all strings that ·match· the
> [`NCName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCName) production in [Namespaces in XML].  The ·lexical space·
> of ID is the set of all strings that ·match· the [`NCName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCName)
> production in [[Namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#XMLNS)]. The ·base type· of ID is
> [`NCName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#NT-NCName).

The NCName production limits the characters that can be used:

> ```
> [4] NCName ::= NCNameStartChar NCNameChar*    /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
> [5] NCNameChar ::= NameChar - ':'
> [6] NCNameStartChar ::= NameStartChar - ':'
> [4] NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                       [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | 
>                       [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                       [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                       [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> [4a] NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | 
>                   [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
> ```

Among the many constraints, note in particular that ***`xs:ID`s cannot have `:` characters anywhere in the name and cannot have a digit as the first character of the name.***

Therefore, your `ID_123` is a proper `NCName`, but `123` is not because it begins with a digit.